# Purpose of the questions in the Visa Waiver ESTA Application Guide

Tags: esta

What's the point of asking:

“Do you seek to engage in or have you ever engaged in terrorist activities, espionage, sabotage, or genocide?”

Do they expect to catch many honest terrorists, war criminals and spies with that?

Comment: Just fill it and move on. No point pondering over it.

Comment: No, they expect to catch some dishonest ones with it. They will say "no" and then any evidence of such prior actions are grounds for deporting them for failing to answer the question honestly.